# Vlan configuration in oracle virtualbox with windows guest os

Tags: virtualbox, vlan

I have a vm with a guest os of win7 enterprise in oracle virtualbox. I am totally new to using it. I need the guest os to send vlan tagged packets. I have done the same in vmware but here I can't. I googled and searched many articles but all are related to solaris or linux. Is vlan tagging supported for a windows guest os. If yes, is there any documentation for configuring it?

Any link related to this also will be helpful to me.

Comment: You can try to add the tag in the network driver option in the guest os.

Comment: i dnt  see any option to configure vlan id in my network driver. My host ethernet adapter is Marvel Yukon and for vm i have assigned it as Intel Pro 100/1000 MT Desktop. I can see that vlan option is enabled but i couldnt find a place to configure the vlan id in my vm